# Horizontal line which starts from right border and ends with left page margin

Tags: line, addlines

I want to have a such line in title page 
[image]
So it will start from the right border of the page and finish with the left margin 
I use document class book.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\rule{\paperwidth}{2pt}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

...or, if I misunderstood the question:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\rule{\paperwidth}{2pt}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Steven. Who knows why when answering a beautiful woman, the answers come right away. Ciaoooo :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I was just following the `\rule`s.